# Math.log() in Java not working as expected

Tags: java, math, logarithm

I am a bit confused right now. My code looks as follows:

```
double pc = 0.125;
double po = 0.2;  
double product = pc*Math.log(pc/po);
System.out.println(product);
```

I would expect the result to be -0,025514997
instead it outputs -0.4700036292457356

Where is the problem???

Comment: What log are you looking for? This is the natural log (e)

Comment: What do you expect that [`Math.log()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-) does? It calculates the natural logarithm (that is, base e) of the number that you give it and the natural log of (0.125 / 0.2 =) 0.625 is -0,47000363.

Comment: already solved the issue: Math.log is the natural algorithm Math.log10() does what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void test() {
    double pc = 0.125;
    double po = 0.2;
    System.out.println("pc * Math.log(pc / po) = " + pc * Math.log(pc / po));
    System.out.println("pc * Math.log10(pc / po) = " + pc * Math.log10(pc / po));
}
```

prints

> pc * Math.log(pc / po) = -0.05875045365571695
>
> pc * Math.log10(pc / po) = -0.0255149978319906

proving that a) there's something wrong with your question - `pc * Math.log(pc / po)` results in `-0.05875045365571695` not `-0.4700036292457356` and b) that you need to use `log10` to get base 10 logs.

Answer (score 4):

```
Math.log(a); // log e

Math.log10(a); // base 10 

Math.log(x)/Math.log(2); // log 2

Math.log(x)/Math.log(your_own); // log your_own
```